# Capturing Last match using Reg Ex

Tags: regex

My String looks likes this

> **Dec 04 08:14:23 198.19.71.200** **Dec 04 08:14:23 198.19.71.201**

Where highligted string consist of two ip address

I am using below regex to capture ip's

> (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)

Now i want to capture the last ip. How would i capture the last ip since my regex is capturing both the ip's ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: Iterate through your captured groups and select the last one?

Comment: I don't know, what language/tool are you working with? I mean, you're not just using regular expressions out of the blue, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
((\d+\.){3}\d+)(?!.*(\d+\.){3}\d+)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/i1JqxDKNMB)

Also slightly simplified the main regex and made it more specific to  dots.